# OpenMP on os x assembler errors

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I've been trying to make openMp work on my mac. In the end i finally managed to get it done , sort of.

This program works perfectly

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_hello.c

But this one :

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static long num_steps = 100000;
double step;

int main(){

int i, nthreads;
double x,pi,sum[2] ;
double start = omp_get_wtime();
double end;

step = 1.0/(double)num_steps;

omp_set_num_threads(2);

#pragma omp parallel
{
    int i, id,nthrds;
    double x;
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    if(id == 0) nthreads = nthrds;

    for(i = 0 ; i < num_steps ; i = i+nthrds){
        x = (i+0.5)*step;
        sum[id] += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
        //printf("Thread_num : %d ,%f\n", omp_get_thread_num(),sum);
    }

}
//pi = step*sum;

for (int i = 0, pi =0.0; i < nthreads; ++i)
{
    /* code */
    pi += sum[i] * step;
}

end = omp_get_wtime();
printf("%f\n", end-start);

return 0;
}
```

..throws me these erros

```
gcc -fopenmp helloWorld.c -o helloWorld
/var/folders/d7/2jjg9ygj7zscb67wnskcxsk40000gp/T//cc4hIbK6.s:19:suffix         or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/d7/2jjg9ygj7zscb67wnskcxsk40000gp/T//cc4hIbK6.s:64:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/d7/2jjg9ygj7zscb67wnskcxsk40000gp/T//cc4hIbK6.s:68:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/d7/2jjg9ygj7zscb67wnskcxsk40000gp/T//cc4hIbK6.s:69:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
```

I have no idea why it does this. I searched the net before i asked here  , but i couldn't find someone who had this problem with openMP.

(I'm not entirely sure that compiler is well installed either. I installed a bunch of things ,some of them worked , some didn't)

Comment: OpenMP only revealed the problem. Looks like your `as` (or maybe `gcc` itself) is too old.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that will read this :
I updated gcc (using brew) and then run the program with gcc-5 .. . Hope you guys make it work too. Best of luck.